# Spread between Microstrategy Marketcap and Bitcoin Holdings

Tags: stock-market, bitcoin

If you look up MicroStrategy on https://bitcointreasuries.net/, you can see that the company's market cap is about twice as high as the value of the Bitcoin it holds.

Where does that spread come from? At a first guess, one would say that the other half of the valuation is Microstrategy's original core business (Business Intelligence Software). However, that is clearly not the case, because the valuation of the company before they started putting Bitcoin onto their balance sheet was significantly lower than that, and there was very little investment taking place because MicroStrategy rather spent that money on purchasing Bitcoin.

So why is the market valuing the company so much higher than what it seems to be worth?